# C#: How to call a method while forcing different marshalling?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, binding

A method declared in one of Microsoft's Primary Interop assemblies is wrong.

It is declared as:

```
void Write(object[] psarray);
```

which is incorrect, and should actually be declared as:

```
void Write([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)] object[] psarray);
```

I need to force the compiler to use `[In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]`, when calling the original method.

I'm not opposed to doing something *like*:

```
object[] parameters = new Object[1];
parameters[0] = theStringIWantedToPass;

thing.GetType().InvokeMethod(
      "write", 
      BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
      null,
      thing, 
      parameters);
```

But I have to know how to override **InvokeMethod** to use **UnmanagedType.SafeArray** marshalling.

***Note:*** I say "like", since I don't know if using reflection to invoke a method can even accomplish what I need. The point was I'm not opposed to calling methods the long way, or loading registers and issuing assembly JMP instructions, as long as .NET allows that sort of thing.

---

**Note:** I cannot re-declare the class with a different signature, since that's then a different class.

Comment: i was specifically trying to avoid naming the PIA, as people might suggest things that don't answer, or workaround, the question. It's in Microsoft.mshtml PIA. HTMLDocumentClass.write() method has the wrong signature.

Answer (score 2):

One way to overcome this shortcoming would be to disassemble the PIA, fix the problem and then rebuild.

It's not the first time either me or a buddy of mine have had to do this in the past with interop assemblies.

Comment: That's what we end up doing too (way too often). ILDASM for the win!

Comment: *hangs head* (Add 15 more characters so i'm allowed to add the comment)